# Using Shader model 5 but getting maximum vs_4_0_level_9_3 error

Tags: c++, directx-11

basically I have this simple register that I use inside my vertex shader for animation purposes

```
cbuffer cbSkinned : register(b3)
{
    float4x4 boneTransforms[96];
};
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to compile my shader/application despite the fact that I've created both my vertex & shader using _5_0. Is Visual Studio somehow forcing me to use vs_4_0_xxx?

Looking forward for some replies, thanks.

Comment: Apparently my Visual Studio is compiling the shaders at SM2, tinkered with the settings and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio defaults to building HLSL files as `xx_4_0_level_9_1` which works on all Direct3D feature level devices. All the 10level9 shader profiles work by building the same code twice: once for Shader Model 4.0 which is used on Direct3D 10.0 or later devices, and once with Shader Model 2.0 for 9.x devices. Since SM 2.0 is a lot more restrictive, it often fails due to SM 2.0 limits. In this case, you are trying to use 384 shader constant slots (each one is a float4) and Shader Model 2.0 only mandates 256 such shader constant slots.

If you changed the target profile to Shader Model 4.0 or greater, likely this would build without any issues. Remember that if you use Shader Model 5.0 profiles, it can only be used on Direct3D Feature Level 11.0, 11.1, 12.0, or 12.1 devices.

See [Direct3D Feature Levels](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels.aspx) and [HLSL, FXC, and D3DCompile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx)